# 2-legged OAuth Security for RestFul API for Jersey

Tags: rest, oauth, jersey, oauth-2.0

I know... I know... there are a lot of articles, resources, etc out there regarding how OAuth and security RestFul APIs with it; however, I'm looking for an actual open-source or third-party product that's already built that I can throw in front of my controllers (as a filter or whatnot) and do my OAuth magic.

I'm perfectly happy (and mostly able) to "roll my own", but if there is already a commercial product out there I would be VERY happy to use it. I mean... I could create my own wheel, but so many other people do it so much better than I could.

I'm using Jersey (JSR-311) as my RestFul framework, not Spring, so I would prefer to not add the extra "weight" of the Spring Security libraries in my application.

Sorry to ask a question I'm sure has been asked 1 zillion times, but I just can't seem to find a very straight-forward product.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jersey oauth module supports 2-legged OAuth.

Server-side OAuth support javadoc: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-server/index.html

Client-side OAuth support javadoc: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-client/index.html

(both are linked from the Jersey home page - http://jersey.java.net)

The modules are available on maven. See http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.jersey.contribs.jersey-oauth%22

If you run into issues, you can contact the Jersey team at users@jersey.java.net.

Comment: I've downloaded Jersey... i don't have any classes that start with the OAuth*. I have jersey 1.12

Comment: I've added some links to my original answer.

Comment: Thanks... I will go ahead and grab the rest of the jars!

Comment: Hey Martin... is it safe to assume you are one of the developers of Jersey? I seem to see someone named Martin all over the Jersey Forums, etc... if you are... can you provide some examples of how to incorporate 2-legged OAuth with Jersey on Web Logic?

Comment: The Javadoc links are broken. The `/latest/` part of the URLs is not working, but replacing that with the latest version, e.g. https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.17/jersey/contribs/jersey-oauth/oauth-server/index.html , then it works.

Comment: OAuth 1.x support has not been migrated from Jersey 1.x to Jersey 2.x  yet. You can find this in the Jersey documentation : https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html